# react-select move input cursor left/right

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am wondering is there a way to be able to move the input cursor inside [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) component from left to right with arrow keys? That would help to see a long text inside it.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code in this specific case ? is it `isMulti` or single etc ?

Comment: I have all kind of react-select use-cases. If anyone can do it for a simple one (or any one) I will probably can extend it to my cases. I just have no clue how where to start.